# jQuery validation plugin - Force checkbox validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having trouble with a form that uses [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
<form name="step1" ...>
    <input type="text" name="name" required="required"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="acceptTerms1" required="required"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="acceptTerms2" required="required"/>
</form>
```

**name** field is being validated, but those two checkboxes are just ignored.

I also tried to set rules manually for them:

```
$('form[name="step1"]').validate({
    ignore: ":hidden:not(.force-validation, .force-validation :input)", //Not ignoring checkboxes (just for information)
    //...
    rules: {
        "acceptTerms1": 'required',
        "acceptTerms2": 'required'
    }
});
```

But the rules are still ignored. What could be missing?

Comment: Your code is working fine exactly as you've shown it to us:  http://jsfiddle.net/sey03p57/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rule should be applied like this:

```
rules: {
  acceptTerms1: {
      required: true
  }
  acceptTerms2: {
      required: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still... `required="required"` should work too, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes. that should. 'required' is HTML's feature and browser should handle it. you can also just use `<input type="checkbox" required name="something">`

Comment: FYI - the jQuery Validate plugin will pickup and use `required="required"` while it dynamically disables the browser's HTML5 validation.

Comment: @CarlosCarucce, this cannot be the answer.  Your shorthand is acceptable and there was nothing wrong with how you declared your rules in the first place:  http://jsfiddle.net/sey03p57/